# virtual img src to real path

Tags: php, image, .htaccess

I assigned an ID to every image in database table which also have the real path to the image including the real name like

```
Table images {
id = '23432.jpg',
path = 'foo/bar',
name = 'baz.jpg' }
```

Is it possible to keep img src="2343.jpg" and get the image from the path [path/name] without using 'data:image/jpg;base64' just the table id[23432.jpg]?

Or is it an .htaccess work!

Comment: Your question doesn't clarify what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: `<img src="script.php?2343.jpg">` and `script.php` reads and outputs content of the image file with corresponding `content-type` header. or, yes, you can use mod_rewrite to hide requests to the `script.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<img src="/images/1234.jpg">` and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ script.php?$1 [L]
```

Redirects all requests to subdir `images` to script.php and puts into the query_string requested filename. All you need is to get it in the script, find corresponding image in DB, read it from disk and output with correct `content-type` header. Or output 404 error if image was not in DB.

Answer (score -1):

Here assuming that path variable has path of image and name is name of image file.

So, you have to give mysql query first to get path and image name from table.

```
$q1="select path,name from images where id=".$id;
$rs=mysql_query($q1);


 while($r=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
 {
      $path=$r[0];
      $imgname=$r[1];

      $completeimgpath=$path."/".$imgname;
      echo "<img src=".$completeimgpath." width=300 height=300 />"
   }
```